not reacting to any events in cog
My bot does not react to the any event in nextcord. Its set up in a cog. Outside of cogs (e.g main.py) Everthng is working fine, but in a cog, no event is registerd or handled. Yes, the bot has the needed permissions (administrator).
Here's my cog loading script
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for filename in os.listdir('cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            try:
                client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
            except Exception as exception:
                traceback.print_exc()
                log.log(exception)
                channel = client.get_channel(config.ERROR_LOG_CHANNEL_ID)
                embed = nextcord.Embed(title=f"Failed to load {filename[:-3]}.",
                                       description=f"{exception}")
                await channel.send(embed=embed)

Here's a snipped of a cog:
import traceback
import asyncio
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands
from static import config
from schildi import utils
import datetime
import os
from schildi import log


def user_action_embed(action: str, user: nextcord.Member, color: int, extra: str | None):
    embed = nextcord.Embed(title="Audit Log Eintrag erstellt", description=action,
                           timestamp=datetime.datetime.now(), color=color)
    embed.add_field(name="User", value=f"{user.mention} - {user.name}\n||{user.id}||", inline=False)
    if extra:
        embed.add_field(name="Zusatz", value=extra, inline=False)
    return embed


class log_listener(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_audit_log_entry_create(self, entry: nextcord.AuditLogEntry):
        print(entry.action)
        log_channel = self.client.get_channel(config.AUDIT_LOG_CHANNEL)
        if entry.action == nextcord.AuditLogAction.thread_create:
            await log_channel.send(embed=user_action_embed(
                action="Thread create",
                user=entry.user,
                extra=f"{entry.extra.channel.mention}",
                color=0x3efa5e))
        if entry.action == nextcord.AuditLogAction.thread_delete:
            await log_channel.send(embed=user_action_embed(
                action="Thread delete",
                user=entry.user,
                extra=f"{entry.extra.channel.mention}",
                color=0x3efa5e))
        if entry.action == nextcord.AuditLogAction.thread_update:
            await log_channel.send(embed=user_action_embed(
                action="Thread create",
                user=entry.user,
                extra=f"{entry.extra.channel.mention}",
                color=0x3efa5e))


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(log_listener(client))

Am i doing something wrong here?

I've just checked and encountered that the bot actually doesnt react to events at all in cogs.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

you forgot closing } in description=f"{exception") and this can raise error - and it may not load it.

i've tried it, still no reactions to events

about you print, in the cog script it prints, in the class it does but in the Cog listener it does not react

maybe better create minimal reproducible example which we could simply copy and run.

I'm not sure but in some examples I see it uses await to execute await client.add_cog(..) and this can makes difference.

nope, no difference

did you try with other events? Maybe it doesn't know on_guild_audit_log_entry_create. Did you try to use CamelCaseName for class like in many examples - class class LogListener?

no other events are reacting either. What is camelcasename? I've read a bot aout it but did not figure out what is does

CamelCaseNames, not camelcasenames - it is using names with upper case chars but without _ (so they looks like camels) - for exampke LogListener instead of log_listener - it helps to recognize class in code. More in PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code

if other events not react then you may have to something wrong in different place. Maybe you run code which catch all events and it doesn't send it to other code - e.g. on_message() without bot.process_commands(msg)

Ahh now i see what these CamelCaseNames are, tyty. It just does not react to any events inside cogs, Outside it does react to every event that it should react to

the only idea is to change settings for logging because it may hide error messages - Setting Up Logging

i did, i've checked the logs and the bot correctly recieves the events

I have no idea - if after changing settings in logging to see all errors you don't get any information then i have no idea what is wrong. I had only two ideas: (1) you didn't run code which register cog (but prints shows that you run it) (2) code raise some error but logging hide it - but you say that it doesn't add any new information. I can't run it to test it so I can't help more.

Yeah idk either why it wont work :/, but anyways thanks for your help :D
